# openVPN server installation over single port?

Tags: vpn, apache-http-server, webserver, openvpn

First of all please understand that i am new to this i need to clear technical term before i actually do any research over it so please ignore my illitracy over the subject..

My company have VPN in place and all intranet is inside that vpn.

Info : The installed vpn server on intranet will not allow connections from mobile devices, tablet and such or it will be hard to configure it. So please leave the thougth of modifying existing VPN for client access.

We made a new webserver which will monitor status and stuff on demand from mobile/browsers etc. Which will be accessed by selected few people.

Now suppose we FORWARD or allow the port 80 (or whatever apache is on) of new webserver to access via internet (to facilitate accessing the info from internet)

So we literally by passing the intranet security (vpn). Now suppose i want to install OpenVPN on the webserver is it possible to do all the configuration over only a single port (i.e 80) ? So suppose some one have to access the website he should enter the webserver (openvpn) credentials than access the website and enter the credentials (php + mysql) of it too.. I do not want to expose any other port or any other network resource over the internet. It will be lethal.

So if i lost it anywhere. We do not want to use the existing VPN. But we need VPN security for the sensitive data on the server. So we want openVPN on webserver because it is easy to config and connect from client point of view also many devices will have inbuilt vpn client which easyly connect with openVPN as observed.

Any other suggestion over the security of the webserver on internet ? if we able to forward the port.

Also i do not know the technical term for it. I mean vpn over a single port ?

Comment: Any one kindly ?

Comment: Just use ngrok, or ssh '__')? https://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/38-You-may-not-need-localtunnel-or-ngrok.html